# How to get the amount of visitors from another website

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering how I could get the visitor amount of other websites. Say for example
I give some bloggers some lines of code that they paste into their own websites, and from
there I get information about how many times that webpage has been been visited.

Do I need to do some kind of `iframe` thing? How would I do this?

Comment: [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?

Comment: You could host your own [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), which I think uses either a bit of JS or a tracking pixel. Just give your bloggers the tracking stuff, and Piwik should do the rest.

Comment: Use this solution http://api.shephertz.com/app-analytics.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand my answer from the comment, if you wanted to start logging and tracking your own analytics, start by providing the 'lines of code' with a track-back tag to differentiate the in-coming links.

Lines of code provided to affiliates:

```
<a href="someblogpost.php?trackback=true" title="Link to Originator's Website">
   To My Site
</a>
```

Once the user enters the header your `someblogpost.php`, you perform any checks if trackback exists.

```
/**
 *  is it a track back from one of your links?
**/
$isTrackback = ( ( isset( $_GET["trackback"] ) 
                  && $_GET["trackback"] == 'true' ) ? true : false );

/**
 *  If so, begin data collecting..
**/
if ( $isTrackback ) {

    //Some Info
    $From = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    $When = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('now'));

    //Inserts the Information into the Db
    InsertVisitorToCounter( $From, $When, $Other.. );
}
```

It's very true that as Yair Nevet mentioned, it'll be much better if you use Google Analytics, as then you can filter, target and comb through much deeper amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

Your link could be a 1px iframe that has a script running on your server.

```
<iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com/somescript.php" height="1px" width="1px"></iframe>
```

It's entirely up to you what that script tracks, it could log every time its viewed.

```
<?php 
   $oldviews = $oldviews; // get the old views from wherever

   // increment per view? obviously you should be cross-checking against the visitors IP address, someone could just be reloading the page 20 times and it would be logged
$newviews = $oldviews + 1; 

// put into the database or text file (wherever you'd store it)...

?>
```

Comment: I would add a query-params to the URL in order to know which site you're on. like: ?siteId="something"

Comment: @YairNevet - yes there would need to be something like that in the url if you wanted to access it. I'm currently looking if you can do something with javascript to grab the parent url :)

Comment: This is my point, you can't. This is why I'm offering to use query-params. like `$GET["SiteId"]`

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't read your answer correctly, minds adrift somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, you can do it like that: `parent.document.getElementById(window.name);` but it's pointless because I think you want it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use free online third-parties tools for that (as I mentioned in the comments) or to write your own visits counter in JavaScript (AJAX), but you should take on account that there is a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue here because I assume you would want to update another domain with your counting.

Answer (score 0):

set allow logging on your web host server, then access the log file from any third party software uses (web analytics)